# metabox checkbox value is not updating

Tags: wordpress

data gets updated correctly in the the database. however, when i'm in WP, the checkboxes don't get the values correctly...they all show up as unchecked. any thoughts on how to do this.
Thanks in advance

```
/* Fire our meta box setup function on the post editor screen. */
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'smashing_post_meta_boxes_setup' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'smashing_post_meta_boxes_setup' );

/* Meta box setup function. */
function smashing_post_meta_boxes_setup() {

    /* Add meta boxes on the 'add_meta_boxes' hook. */
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'smashing_add_post_meta_boxes' );

    /* Save post meta on the 'save_post' hook. */
    add_action( 'save_post', 'smashing_flautist_access_save_meta', 10, 2 );
}

/* Create one or more meta boxes to be displayed on the post editor screen. */
function smashing_add_post_meta_boxes() {

    add_meta_box(
        'smashing-flautist-access',         // Unique ID
        esc_html__( 'Post Viewing Permission', 'smashing_flautist' ),       // Title
        'smashing_flautist_access_meta_box',        // Callback function
        'destinations',                 // Admin page (or post type)
        'normal',                   // Context
        'default'                   // Priority
    );
}

/* Display the post meta box. */
function smashing_flautist_access_meta_box( $object, $box ) { ?>

    <?php wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'smashing_flautist_access_nonce' ); ?>


<table class="smashing-flautist-access">
<tr align="left">
<th>Username</th>
<th>    </th>
<th>Visiblity</th>
<th>    </th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
<?php
global $post;
    $users = get_users('role=subscriber');
    foreach ($users as $user) {
            $user_info = get_userdata( $user->ID );
            if(get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'smashing_flautist_access', true ) == $user->user_login) $ifchecked = 'checked="checked" ';
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$user->user_login</td><td>    </td>";
            echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"smashing-flautist-access\" id=\"smashing-flautist-access\" value=\"$user->user_login\" " . $ifchecked ."/></td><td>  </td>";
            echo "<td>$user_info->last_name, $user_info->first_name</td><td>    </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            unset($ifchecked);

    } ?></table>


<?php }

/* Save post meta on the 'save_post' hook. */
add_action( 'save_post', 'smashing_flautist_access_save_meta', 10, 2 );

/* Save the meta box's post metadata. */
function smashing_flautist_access_save_meta( $post_id, $post ) {

    /* Make all $wpdb references within this function refer to this variable */
    global $wpdb;

    /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
    if ( !isset( $_POST['smashing_flautist_access_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['smashing_flautist_access_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return $post_id;

    /* Get the post type object. */
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

    /* Check if the current user has permission to edit the post. */
    if ( !current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['smashing-flautist-access'] ) ? sanitize_html_class( $_POST['smashing-flautist-access'] ) : '' );

    /* Get the meta key. */
    $meta_key = 'smashing_flautist_access';

    /* Get the meta value of the custom field key. */
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true );

    /* If a new meta value was added and there was no previous value, add it. */
    if ( $new_meta_value && '' == $meta_value )
        {
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value, true );
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_status = 'private' WHERE ID = ".$post_id." AND post_type ='post'"));
        }
    /* If the new meta value does not match the old value, update it. */
    elseif ( $new_meta_value && $new_meta_value != $meta_value )
        {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value );
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_status = 'private' WHERE ID = ".$post_id." AND post_type ='post'"));
        }
    /* If there is no new meta value but an old value exists, delete it. */
    elseif ( '' == $new_meta_value && $meta_value )
        {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
        $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $wpdb->posts SET post_status = 'public' WHERE ID = ".$post_id." AND post_type ='post'"));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if(get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'smashing_flautist_access', true ) == $user->user_login) $ifchecked = 'checked="checked" ';
```

Try:

```
$ifchecked = (get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'smashing_flautist_access', true ) == $user->user_login)? 'CHECKED ':'';
```

Using this, you can also remove the `unset($ifchecked);` as you are always assigning `$ifchecked` a new value in each iteration. The `unset` doesn't hurt anything, it's just not necessary.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: Thank you it is showing checked now,but when i select multiple checkbox it is displaying only one checkbox checked.

Comment: When you are saving them back to the database, it looks like you are only saving one. There is no loop to process multiple checkboxes.  It looks to me like ``smashing_flautist_access`` will come back as an array of values but you are treating it as a single value. So no, it wouldn't save more than one to the DB.

Comment: Could you please provide me complete working code?thanks

Comment: Nope. But my guess is that if you ``print_r($_POST['smashing_flautist_access_nonce'])`` you will see that it is an array of values. So everything after you check the nonce should probably be inside a foreach() loop. I looks like you need to do all of those things for each ``smashing_flautist_access_nonce`` you get back. No?